# Why isn't the text in `tabularx` vertically centered when math stacking commands are used?

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, align, tabularx, stackengine

When I try to use math environments with stacking features, such as `\Vectorstack` from `stackengine` package, the text will not longer be vertically centered in the cell. Rather, it goes upwards as if it was ragged to the top. Here is an example

[image]

What is even stranger is that disabling the command `\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{>{\Centering}m{#1}}` solves it. Ironically, that command in particular is used to enable vertical centering so how come that its presence is what prevents vertical centering?

My source code

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{amsmath,array,booktabs,multirow}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\newcolumntype{C}{ >{\arraybackslash \Centering}X
                }
\newcolumntype{R}{ >{\arraybackslash \RaggedLeft}X
                }
\newcolumntype{L}{ >{\arraybackslash \RaggedRight}X
                }
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{>{\Centering}m{#1}}


\usepackage{stackengine}
\newcommand{\stackanchormath}[3][\stackgapSdefaultl]{
    \stackanchor[#1]{$#2$}{$#3$}
                                                    }
\newcommand{\stackgapSdefault}{
    \setstackgap{S}{\stackgapSdefaultl}
                            }

\newlength{\stackgapSdefaultl}
\setlength{\stackgapSdefaultl}{1.06mm}
\setstackgap{S}{\stackgapSdefaultl}





\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{0.7\columnwidth}{>{\hsize=0.75\hsize}R |L}
    \toprule
    %
    \texttt{$\backslash$Vectorstack} & Test \Vectorstack[c]{ {e = mc^{2}} {y = a x + b} } text
    \\
    \hline
    \texttt{$\backslash$stackanchormath} & Test \stackanchormath{e=mc^{2}}{y = a x + b} text
    \\
    \hline
    \texttt{aligned} & Test $\begin{aligned} e &= mc^{2} \\ y &= a x + b \end{aligned}$ text
    %
    \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `{>{\hsize=0.75\hsize}R |L}` this is wrong. You need the `\hsizes` total to stay the same: if you have 2 `X` columns, the total should add up to 2 and not 1.75. Also, remember that what gets aligned is baselines. Also, don't use `booktabs` rules with vertical rules.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue arises because your `R` and `L` columns are type `X`, which is set in auto-wrap paragraph mode.  Thus, any vertical alignments set by the particular stacking mechanism (e.g., `\Vectorstack`) are subsumed by the vertical paragraph alignments of the `X` column.

For comparison, I show the `tabularx` twice: 1st as originally given (`R L` with the last cell extended to show the auto-wrap feature activated), and then with the column types changed to (non-wrapping) `r l` columns.  As you can see in the 2nd case, baseline alignments are preserved.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{amsmath,array,booktabs,multirow}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\newcolumntype{C}{ >{\arraybackslash \Centering}X
                }
\newcolumntype{R}{ >{\arraybackslash \RaggedLeft}X
                }
\newcolumntype{L}{ >{\arraybackslash \RaggedRight}X
                }
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{>{\Centering}m{#1}}


\usepackage{stackengine}
\newcommand{\stackanchormath}[3][\stackgapSdefaultl]{
    \stackanchor[#1]{$#2$}{$#3$}
                                                    }
\newcommand{\stackgapSdefault}{
    \setstackgap{S}{\stackgapSdefaultl}
                            }

\newlength{\stackgapSdefaultl}
\setlength{\stackgapSdefaultl}{1.06mm}
\setstackgap{S}{\stackgapSdefaultl}





\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{0.7\columnwidth}{R L}
    \toprule
    %
    \texttt{$\backslash$Vectorstack} & Test \Vectorstack[c]{ {e = mc^{2}} {y = a x + b} } text
    \\
    \hline
    \texttt{$\backslash$stackanchormath} & Test \stackanchormath{e=mc^{2}}{y = a x + b} text
    \\
    \hline
    \texttt{aligned} & Test $\begin{aligned} e &= mc^{2} \\ y &= a x + b \end{aligned}$ text is in paragraph form and auto-wraps
    %
    \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\begin{tabularx}{0.7\columnwidth}{r l}
    \toprule
    %
    \texttt{$\backslash$Vectorstack} & Test \Vectorstack[c]{ {e = mc^{2}} {y = a x + b} } text
    \\
    \hline
    \texttt{$\backslash$stackanchormath} & Test \stackanchormath{e=mc^{2}}{y = a x + b} text
    \\
    \hline
    \texttt{aligned} & Test $\begin{aligned} e &= mc^{2} \\ y &= a x + b \end{aligned}$ text
    %
    \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that alignment with `X` columns can be recovered if the appropriate `\vphantom` is applied to the left-hand side to match the right-hand side:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{amsmath,array,booktabs,multirow}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\newcolumntype{C}{ >{\arraybackslash \Centering}X
                }
\newcolumntype{R}{ >{\arraybackslash \RaggedLeft}X
                }
\newcolumntype{L}{ >{\arraybackslash \RaggedRight}X
                }
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{>{\Centering}m{#1}}


\usepackage{stackengine}
\newcommand{\stackanchormath}[3][\stackgapSdefaultl]{
    \stackanchor[#1]{$#2$}{$#3$}
                                                    }
\newcommand{\stackgapSdefault}{
    \setstackgap{S}{\stackgapSdefaultl}
                            }

\newlength{\stackgapSdefaultl}
\setlength{\stackgapSdefaultl}{1.06mm}
\setstackgap{S}{\stackgapSdefaultl}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{0.7\columnwidth}{R L}
    \toprule
    %
    \texttt{$\backslash$Vectorstack}\vphantom{\Vectorstack[c]{ {e = mc^{2}} {y = a x + b} }} 
    & Test \Vectorstack[c]{ {e = mc^{2}} {y = a x + b} } text
    \\
    \hline
    \texttt{$\backslash$stackanchormath} \vphantom{\stackanchormath{e=mc^{2}}{y = a x + b}} 
    & Test \stackanchormath{e=mc^{2}}{y = a x + b} text
    \\
    \hline
    \texttt{aligned} \vphantom{$\begin{aligned} e &= mc^{2} \\ y &= a x + b \end{aligned}$}
    & Test $\begin{aligned} e &= mc^{2} \\ y &= a x + b \end{aligned}$ text
    %
    \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}


\end{document}
```

[image]